# Cannot display a JSON object field in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api

I want to make an app that shows the current weather in the user's location using darksky.com API. But right now I can't even get the temperature to be printed on the console. Here is my code :

```
var link = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/037352c0951701a563b624359ea6111f"; //link with key
getLocation();
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } 
}

function showPosition(position) {
   link  += "/" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude; //getting the coordinates
 $.getJSON( "https://crossorigin.me/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/037352c0951701a563b624359ea6111f/42.3601,-71.0589" , function( json.current.weather ) { console.log( "JSON Data: " + json); })
});
}
```

Comment: check the key. It appears to be wrong

Comment: You cannot access keys like that in this situation, it works like an alias for the response data

Answer (score 1):

You have a few syntax errors going on. You have too many parenthesis and you are trying to use the dot object notation in your getJSON response. With `function(json) {`, your function parameter is like an alias. json.property will not do anything and will cause an error.

If your response object had current.weather, that syntax is right but it needs to be nested inside the callback function. For ex..

```
 $.getJSON(url, function(json) {

  var data = json.current.weather;
  console.log("JSON Data:", json, data);

 });
```

See ex: https://jsfiddle.net/vz8obeqj/2/